# Using select query data dont get completely from a field

Tags: mysql

I am trying for select data from database.I have a table with name mail_header,with field id,content.I have only one row of data in table.Mysql is database

**Used these select query**

```
$header="select * from mail_header where id='1'";
$header2=mysql_query($header);
$fet=mysql_fetch_array($header2);
echo $fet['content'];
```

**Table structure**

```
+----+--------------------------+
| id |    content               |
+====+==========================+
| 1  |    nextiva<nextiva.com>  |
+----+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :
echo htmlentities($fet['content']);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$header="select * from mail_header";
$header2=mysql_query($header);
while ($fet=mysql_fetch_array($header2)){
   echo htmlentities($fet['content']);
}
```

Comment: Got content as nextiva,dont get nextiva<nextiva.com>,dont get complete contet

Comment: what is the data type of your `content` column?